# Remedy for both revision and filename

Tags: git

I've seen this error in other parts of the forum, but never in this particular situation.

I'm a git beginner. I am trying:

```
gitk file.py
```

but I get

```
ambiguous argument file.py: both revision and filename.
```

How do I rename the revision so I don't have this issue?

This happened after I branched the `file.py`. Why?

Comment: You can't branch files in git.  `git branch -d file.py` will probably sort things out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can force `gitk` to treat the argument as a filename by using `--` before it:

```
gitk -- file.py
```

Alternatively, as you noted, it's a bad practice to have names that are both branch names and file names. You can rename your branch by using `git branch -m`:

```
git branch -m file.py some_other_branch_name
```